# flash cc on OSX - compiling to ios - stops at 05

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

I've been working on a project that requires cross compiling. The project packs and runs correctly for android. I can test the generated .swf file from osx / windows without problem.

My issue is while trying to compile for ios, either on pc or mac, the .ipa generation doesn't happen. On pc, I left the machine for 12 hours and no result was given. On osx, a progress bar stated 1:20 minutes would be needed, it progresses but at 0:05 it just stalls.

How can I work out whats going wrong? 
Is there a log file anywhere?

I can compile other projects without any issues.

Regards.

Comment: Did you check the Console.app to see if there are any error messages? It's in `Applications/Utilities`. Have you upgraded Flash CC to the latest version? What version of Adobe Air are you compiling to?

Comment: Thanks pier, I didn't knew of console app, how does it work?

I'm trying to compile to air version 3.6 and 3.8 on osx. On windows I also tried 3.9

Latest flash cc version, according to adobe application manager

Comment: Open it, and scroll to the bottom. You will see all kind of messages from the system and the apps. If Flash complains, it usually appears there. You can download Air 4.0 and install it in Flash CC in `Help/Manage Air SDKs`, but I don't think that will help.

I had a similar problem and it was caused by an image having an `ñ` in the file name...

Comment: BTW are you using ANEs?

Comment: Thanks, I indeed am using some ANEs, just did a simple project including one of the libraries and it stalls.

Most likely will have to change to unity3d as I need ogg loading / decoding